# Should the Brompton Transit Travel Bag protect my MSL enough in the hold of an aircraft traveling in the UK?

Tags: brompton

Is the Brompton Transit Travel bag designed to protect a Brompton bike in the hold of an aircraft?

Comment: It's really going to depend on how energetic and creative the baggage smashers are feeling on the days you're travelling...

Comment: This is a product opinion question which isn't a great candidate for stack exchange. It will go out of date quickly. Consider making a more general question that is more objective, such as, "What features should I look for in a bike bag/box for air travel to ensure my bike isn't damaged?"

Comment: @DavidW Yeah, I watched an off-center guitar case go up the conveyor belt to the hold of the aircraft, bump against the fuselage, and then fall off the side 3+ meters to the concrete.

Comment: @Michael I vividly recall a flight where I was waiting for the plane to push back when a pair of baggage smashers arrived with a ramp, apparently to retrieve someone's bag.  They had one of those moveable conveyors, but they were just _hurling_ bags out of the cargo door onto the tarmac.  There was one box that, as it flew out, clearly read "Fragile" in red on all sides.  One of them climbed down and, from wherever they'd landed, tossed bags onto the conveyor; if they weren't on properly and fell off partway up, he just did it again.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have first hand experience with it, but the description on the product page highlights that this is for train and plane trips.

The bag features padded side panels that are reinforced with plastic boards for structure and protection as well as other aspects often seen on regular travel suit cases.

Reviews on the product page also suggest it is great, but I encourage you to also seek reviews on other more independent websites.

Bottom line, that is the official product made by the bike manufacturer for carrying the bike on trips and Brompton makes quality bikes, so it is a good indicator that this travel bag should do the thing.